# how to encode NSData to string

Tags: ios, encoding, nsdata

I have a dictionary of NSData values where I am passing the different values into their variables that I later use to display in tableviewcells etc.

However I have some international characters that are not displaying correctly and I would like to encode the data I am passing to a NSString but I am not sure how to do it because of the circumstances.

This is what I am currently doing.

```
manString = [dict valueForKey:@"MAN"];
```

The dict contains all of the data that i am using. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[dict valueForKey:@"MAN"] 
                                         encoding:NSStringEncoding];
```

Where `encoding` should be a value from `NSStringEncoding` enum, you can find it in `NSString.h`, just choose encoding you need, usually it is `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, but I guess not in your case.